# Change system data with deepfreeze

Tags: date-time

I have a mother board with broken BIOS. My time change every time I turn on my computer, even I change the CMOS battery, still won’t save my setting. For able to work on some games and application, I need to update my system date every now and then. My problem is that my computer is installed with deepfreeze. I can’t change the system time. I can’t unfreeze or uninstall the deepfreeze since I’m using it as corrupt/virus protection.

Comment: you can't unfreeze it? why not? if you are worried about virus, then remove it from any network and unfreeze it. But this sounds funny...

Answer (score 1):

1. Disconnect your computer from the network
2. unfreeze the Drive
3. make a batch file containing:

   w`32tm /resync /nowait`

   save it somewhere and make a shortcut for it.
4. Copy that shortcut and save it to your startup folder.
5. open the shortcut properties and set it to start minimized
6. refreeze and update the deepfreeze status
7. reboot with network connected.